# Order by the difference of two columns in Laravel 5.3

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have an eloquent query where one of the orderBy is the difference of two columns.

```
$mymodel = Level::where([['ColA', 5], ['ColB', 10], ['ColC', 7]])
                 ->orderBy('ColA', 'Desc')
                 ->orderBy('ColA' - 'ColB', 'Desc')
                 ->orderBy('ColC', 'Desc')
                 ->orderBy('ColD', 'Asc')
                 ->pluck('userId')->toArray();
```

The exact same code on localhost with sqlite works without an error. But on production with MySQL has the following error

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '0' in 'order clause' (SQL: select `userId` from `levels` where (`ColA` = 5 and `ColB` = 10 and `ColC` = 7) order by `ColA` desc, `0` desc, `ColC` desc, `ColD` asc)
```

Comment: `'ColA' - 'ColB'` you are subtracting strings. Try to put the whole thing in a string.

Comment: Now I have `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ColA-ColB' in 'order clause'`

Comment: Hmm. Try to put parenthesis around.

Comment: I either use with the wrong way the parenthesis, or it still doesn't work :(

Comment: `->orderBy("(ColA - ColB)", 'Desc')` tried like this?

Comment: still the same `SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '(ColA-ColB)' in 'order clause' `

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$model = Level::where($wheres)
              ->orderByRaw('(ColA - ColB) DESC')
              ->pluck('userId')
              ->toArray();
```